# What's the Eclipse keyboard shortcut to select the variable name / to expand the selection?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

**Example**

Given the variable name `myVariableName` and the cursor position denoted with `[cursor]`

```
String [cursor]myVariablenName = new String()
```

What keyboard shortcut selects the entire variable?

**Elaboration**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> only selects `my`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> selects the entire variable name `myVariableName`, but it is too many key strokes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. It invokes the `Select Enclosing Element` command.

It works with all possible cases, for example

```
[cursor]myVariablenName
```

or

```
myVar[cursor]iablenName
```

or

```
myVariablenName[cursor]
```